# firebase new user registration with php sdk

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-authentication

In android, using android sdk we can create new user somehow like this:

```
  mFirebaseRef.createUser(Email, Password, new Firebase.ValueResultHandler<java.util.Map<String, Object>>() {
                public void onSuccess(java.util.Map result) {
                    System.out.println("Successfully created user account with uid: " + result.get("uid"));
                }
                public void onError(com.firebase.client.FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                    System.err.println("Error while creating user " + firebaseError);
                }
```

With PHP sdk how can we create new user in authentication section? Can anyone please tell me. I would be very grateful to you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official PHP SDK for Firebase. If you think there should be one, [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

You will have to call the user-creation methods from the client app directly, or from your server using one of the [supported Admin SDK platforms](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/).

Comment: Well there is one SDK https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php . It also has authentication function, here->http://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/authentication.html .But problem is I am not being able to do further processing.

Comment: Ah, that's a cool SDK. Please edit your question to include that link. But either way, it looks like that library does not include a way to create users. If you want the author to add that functionality, file a feature request here: https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php/issues